# DropDownList's OnSelectedIndexChanged event is not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I have created the time slots....

It is basically Bootstrap code...., I want to execute it in .net for my project purpose....

I have used some DropDownLists in my project .... Their Events didn't work.....

It shows nothing after execute...

my code is as follows....

```
<body>
 <form id="Form1" runat="server">
    <!-- start: Header -->
    <div class="navbar">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- start: Header -->

    <div class="container-fluid-full">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div id="content" class="span10">
                <div class="row-fluid">
                    <div class="box span12">
                        <div class="box-header">
                            <h2><i class="icon-bookmark"></i>Create Event</h2>
                        </div>
                        <div class="box-content">
                            <div id="MyWizard" class="wizard">
                                <ul class="steps">
                                    <li data-target="#step1" class="active"><span class="badge badge-info">1</span></li>
                                    <li data-target="#step2"><span class="badge">2</span></li>
                                    <li data-target="#step3"><span class="badge">3</span></li>
                                    <li data-target="#step4"><span class="badge">4</span></li>
                                    <li data-target="#step5"><span class="badge">5</span></li>
                                </ul>
                                <div class="actions">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-prev"><i class="icon-arrow-left"></i>Prev</button>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-next" data-last="Finish">Next<i class="icon-arrow-right"></i></button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="step-content">
                                <div class="step-pane active" id="step1" runat="server">
                                    <div class="control-group ">
                                        <div class="controls">
                                            <h1>Create a new event<asp:TextBox ID="EventName_TB" runat="server" CssClass="control-label"></asp:TextBox>
                                                starting on 
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="StartDate_TB" runat="server" Style="color: #727272 !important; font-size: 24px; font-weight: 100;" CssClass="span2 input-xlarge datepicker" ></asp:TextBox>
                                                for
                                                <asp:DropDownList ID="EventDuration_DDL" runat="server" Style="color: #727272 !important; font-size: 24px; font-weight: 100;" CssClass="span1" OnSelectedIndexChanged="EventDuration_DDL_SelectedIndexChanged">
                                                    <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
                                                    <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
                                                    <asp:ListItem>3</asp:ListItem>
                                                    <asp:ListItem>4</asp:ListItem>
                                                    <asp:ListItem>5</asp:ListItem>
                                                    <asp:ListItem>6</asp:ListItem>
                                                    <asp:ListItem>7</asp:ListItem>
                                                </asp:DropDownList>
                                                days. </h1>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="step-pane" id="step2" runat="server" visible="false">
                                    <div class="control-group ">
                                        <h1>Matching making will be held on the following days:
                                        <br />
                                            <br />
                                        </h1>

                                        <div class="row-fluid">
                                            <span class="h1size">
                                                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                                            </span>
                                            <div class="make-switch pull-right" data-on="info">
                                                <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Visible="false" />
                                            </div>
                                            <br/>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                                <div class="step-pane" id="step3">

                                    <h1>Matchmaking starts at 
                                        <asp:DropDownList ID="StartTime_DDL" runat="server" Style="color: #727272 !important; font-size: 24px; font-weight: 100;" CssClass="span2">
                                            <asp:ListItem Text="9:00 AM"></asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem Text="9:30 AM"></asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem Text="10:00 AM"></asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem Text="10:30 AM"></asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem Text="11:00 AM"></asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem Text="11:30 AM"></asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem Text="12:00 PM"></asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem Text="12:30 PM"></asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem Text="1:00 PM"></asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem Text="1:30 PM"></asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem Text="2:00 PM"></asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem Text="2:30 PM"></asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem Text="3:00 PM"></asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem Text="3:30 PM"></asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem Text="4:00 PM"></asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem Text="4:30 PM"></asp:ListItem>
                                        </asp:DropDownList>
                                        and ends at
                                        <asp:DropDownList ID="EndTime_DDL" runat="server" Style="color: #727272 !important; font-size: 24px; font-weight: 100;" CssClass="span2">
                                            <asp:ListItem Text="9:00 AM"></asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem Text="9:30 AM"></asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem Text="10:00 AM"></asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem Text="10:30 AM"></asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem Text="11:00 AM"></asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem Text="11:30 AM"></asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem Text="12:00 PM"></asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem Text="12:30 PM"></asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem Text="1:00 PM"></asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem Text="1:30 PM"></asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem Text="2:00 PM"></asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem Text="2:30 PM"></asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem Text="3:00 PM"></asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem Text="3:30 PM"></asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem Text="4:00 PM"></asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem Text="4:30 PM"></asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem Text="5:00 PM"></asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem Text="5:30 PM"></asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem Text="6:00 PM"></asp:ListItem>

                                        </asp:DropDownList>.

                                    <br /><br />
                                        Each slot is 
                                        <asp:DropDownList ID="SlotDuration_DDL" runat="server" Style="color: #727272 !important; font-size: 24px; font-weight: 100;" CssClass="span2" OnSelectedIndexChanged="SlotDuration_DDL_SelectedIndexChanged">

                                            <asp:ListItem>10</asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem>15</asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem>20</asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem>25</asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem>30</asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem>35</asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem>40</asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem>45</asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem>50</asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem>55</asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem>60</asp:ListItem>
                                        </asp:DropDownList>
                                        minutes long. </h1>

                                </div>
                                <div class="step-pane" id="step4">
                                    <div class="control-group ">
                                        <h1>The following slots are available for Matchmaking.
                                            <br/>
                                        </h1>
                                        <div class="alert alert-info">
                                            Turn off any slots you wish to disable.
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="row-fluid">
                                                <div class="span6">
                                            <h1>
                                                    <asp:Label ID="Date_label" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                                </h1>
                                                <div class="task low" runat="server" id="Timediv">

                                                </div>

                                                <div class="clearfix"></div>

                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="step-pane" id="step5">
                                    <h1>Your event is ready!</h1>
                                </div>

                            </div>

                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <!--/span-->

                </div>
                <!--/row-->

            </div>

            <!-- end: Content -->

        </div>
        <!--/fluid-row-->
```

Code Behind....

```
 protected void EventDuration_DDL_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int n = Int32.Parse(EventDuration_DDL.SelectedItem.ToString());

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {

            Label NewLabel = new Label();
            NewLabel.ID = "Label" + i;
            var eventDate = Calendar1.SelectedDate.Date.AddDays(i);
            NewLabel.Text = eventDate.ToLongDateString();

            CheckBox newcheck = new CheckBox();
            newcheck.ID = "CheckBox" + i;

            this.Labeldiv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<span class='h1size'>"));
            this.Labeldiv.Controls.Add(NewLabel);
            this.Labeldiv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</span>"));
            this.Labeldiv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<div class='make-switch pull-right' data-on='info'>"));
            this.Labeldiv.Controls.Add(newcheck);
            this.Labeldiv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</div>"));
            this.Labeldiv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br/>"));
        }  
    }

    protected void SlotDuration_DDL_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Date_label.Text = Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString();
        DateTime start = DateTime.Parse(StartTime_DDL.SelectedItem.Text);
        DateTime end = DateTime.Parse(EndTime_DDL.SelectedItem.Text);
        double duration = double.Parse(SlotDuration_DDL.SelectedItem.Text);
        string header = "<div class='priority low'><span><strong>{0}</strong></span></div>";
        string header1 = "<div class='priority medium'><span><strong>{0}</strong></span></div>";
        string morning = "";
        string afternon = "";
        bool doneMornHeader = false, doneAfternoonHeader = false;
        while (true)
        {
            DateTime dtNext = start.AddMinutes(duration);
            if (start > end || dtNext > end)
                break;
            if (start < DateTime.Parse("12:00 PM"))
            {
                if (!doneMornHeader)
                {
                    Label head = new Label();
                    head.Text = string.Format(header, "Morning");
                    this.Timediv.Controls.Add(head);
                    doneMornHeader = true;
                }
                morning = start.ToShortTimeString() + "-" + dtNext.ToShortTimeString();
                Label lbl = new Label();
                lbl.Text = morning;
                CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();
                this.Timediv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<div class='span6'><div class='task low'>"));
                this.Timediv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<div class='desc'>"));
                this.Timediv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<div class='title'>"));
                this.Timediv.Controls.Add(lbl);
                this.Timediv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<div class='make-switch span5 pull-right' data-on='success'>"));
                this.Timediv.Controls.Add(cb);
                this.Timediv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</div>"));
                this.Timediv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</div>"));
                this.Timediv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</div>"));
                this.Timediv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</div>"));
                this.Timediv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br>"));
            }
            else
            {
                if (!doneAfternoonHeader)
                {
                    Label head = new Label();
                    head.Text = string.Format(header1, "Afternoon");
                    this.Timediv.Controls.Add(head);
                    doneAfternoonHeader = true;
                }
                afternon = start.ToShortTimeString() + "-" + dtNext.ToShortTimeString();
                Label lbl1 = new Label();
                lbl1.Text = afternon;
                CheckBox cb1 = new CheckBox();
                this.Timediv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<div class='span6'><div class='task low'>"));
                this.Timediv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<div class='desc'>"));
                this.Timediv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<div class='title'>"));
                this.Timediv.Controls.Add(lbl1);
                this.Timediv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<div class='make-switch span5 pull-right' data-on='success'>"));
                this.Timediv.Controls.Add(cb1);
                this.Timediv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</div>"));
                this.Timediv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</div>"));
                this.Timediv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</div>"));

                this.Timediv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br>"));

            }
            start = dtNext;
        }
}
```

The Events didn't work..........

any solution please...............!

and one more problem is to add one or more days to the date which is from textbox????

Answer (score 1):

Set to `<asp: DropDownList>` that has the `OnSelectedIndexChanged` event the `AutoPostback = True` and that will work.

Example:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="EventDuration_DDL" runat="server" AutoPostback="True" Style="color: #727272 !important; font-size: 24px; font-weight: 100;" CssClass="span1" OnSelectedIndexChanged="EventDuration_DDL_SelectedIndexChanged" >
```

Comment: when I set AutoPostback=True, It works but It doesnot stay in current step, It goes to 1st step....

Comment: @THOR see the property AutoPostback at the dropdownlist. all ddl that has the onselectedIndexChanged need this property, without that the event never will fired.

Comment: when I set AutoPostback=True, It works but It doesnot stay in current step, It goes to 1st step.... My project is designed as steps wise like wizard in asp.net, after selecting the ddl item, it returns to 1 step...

Answer (score 1):

Try to set `<asp:DropDownList>` **AutoPostBack** to **true**:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="EventDuration_DDL" AutoPostBack="True" runat="server" Style="color: #727272 !important; font-size: 24px; font-weight: 100;" CssClass="span1" OnSelectedIndexChanged="EventDuration_DDL_SelectedIndexChanged">
```

To add days to your `DateTime` use:

```
YourDateTime = YourDateTime.AddDays(1);
```

Comment: when I set AutoPostback=True, It works but It doesnot stay in current step, It goes to 1st step...

Comment: @THOR Because it reloads your page. You can't access to your backend without postback (page reloading). Check out the AJAX...

Comment: @THOR If i'm right and the problem is there then i would try to move logic from server-side to client-side or to use AJAX to call server-side asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

@Thor..for working on dropdown from server side you need to set AutoPostBack property to true and if your design is a wizard step type and it goes to Step 1 then it will be a bad practice, but you can explicitly set the wizard step to your current step after the dropdown processing gets completed.

If you are using a .net wizard then use ajax update panels and then you will remain on current step only.